# Estou tendo um Erro TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
import json

def abrir():
  with open('estoque.txt', 'w+') as nome:
    nomez = str (input('Digite Nome do Produto: '))
    Quant = int (input('Digite Quantidade do produto: '))
    PC = float (input('Digite o Preço de Custo: '))
    PV =  float (input('Digite o Preço de Venda: '))
    
  
    L = [f'{nomez},{Quant}, {PC}, {PV}']
    json.dumps(L)
    nome.write(f'{L}')
def ler(nome):

    with open('estoque.txt', 'rt') as nome:
        print(nome.read())


def alterar(nome):
    with open('estoque.txt', 'r+') as nome:
     print(nome.readlines())
     print(nome[1])
```

> #Quero mostra só um item dentro do arquivo não todos

```
resp = int (input('Digita ae: '))
if resp == 1:
  ler(ler)
elif resp == 2:
  abrir()
elif resp == 3:
  alterar(alterar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o que está causando o erro é a última linha de sua função "alterar", onde você está tratando um objeto de arquivo (nome) como se ele fosse um objeto "indexável":

```
print(nome[1])
```

Quando você executa a linha anterior:

```
print(nome.readlines())
```

Uma lista contendo todas as linhas do arquivo é impressa. Supondo que você queira imprimir apenas a primeira linha (que seria a linha 0, e não a linha 1), você pode conseguir isso simplesmente apagando o "s" em "readlines" de maneira que apenas a primeira linha seja lida. Ou seja, em vez de:

```
print(nome.readlines())
```

Deveria ser:

```
print(nome.readline())
```

Dito isso, se você não quer imprimir a primeira linha (linha 0), e sim alguma outra linha específica, como a segunda linha (linha 1), seguindo mais ou menos a sua lógica, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
# Crie uma referência para a lista contendo as linhas:
linhas = nome.readlines()

# Acesse a linha específica:
print(linhas[1])

# Obs: A função print anterior pode causar IndexError se a linha
# especificada não existir, e pode parecer não imprimir nada, se a
# linha especificada só contiver caracteres em branco ou estiver vazia.
```

Dito todas essas coisas, o seu código parece ter muitos outros problemas... A importação de json que não é usada para nada, a instrução json.dumps(L) que só causa algum efeito no modo iterativo, funções e variáveis com o mesmo nome, parâmetros e variáveis com o mesmo nome, etc.

Me parece que você está tentando resolver um problema específico sem muito conhecimento básico da linguagem. Se for isso, você escolheu a linguagem certa! Python é ótima para esse tipo de coisas! Mesmo assim, sugiro que você aprenda um pouco mais do básico da linguagem para conseguir trabalhar melhor no problema. O próprio site oficial da linguagem (https://www.python.org) possui vários recursos didáticos interessantes, caso esteja interessado.